# What do @backups branches/tags mean in converted svn2git git repository

Tags: svn2git

After converting a SVN repository from SVN to git, I see tags with names like:

```
backups/PM_4_2_11@204843
```

This tag was not in the original SVN repository. Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you **had** that tag in SVN revision 204843, but it was deleted in SVN after that.